# Почему не ставится запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Лгал я(,) или нет — судить не мне.

Answer (score 2):

А где Вы хотите её поставить? Перед или? Но первая часть сложного предложения - простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, союз **или** одиночный.

*Лгал я или нет ...*. Слово "нет" в этом предложении является сказуемым, по смыслу равно "не лгал" — употреблено во избежание повтора. Союз "или" в этом случае соединяет предыдущий глагол и частицу "нет"  как однородные сказуемые.

> Нет - частица. Употребляется вместо сказуемого с отрицанием, а также
> вместо словосочетания или целого предложения с отрицанием, когда они
> противопоставляются предыдущему. Возник спор: одни утверждали, что
> нужно строить дорогу, другие — что нет. Она думала: придёт он или нет.

http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Net-16554.html

**Запятой нет.**

Answer (score 0):

Лгал и нет — это однородные члены, между которыми стоит союз; если между однородными членами стоит союз — запятая не ставится.